# Preventing Triggering of Dependent Events on Updating Parts of a ReactiveValue in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently working on a Shiny application where I have a reactiveValue that contains a list. I am trying to update a part of this list without triggering other events that depend on it.

In the example below, I would like `button_Aa` *not to* trigger `text_Ab`, and likewise `button_Ab` *not to* trigger `text_Aa`. I tried using `isolate` without success.

I am aware I could create separate reactive values for each element of my list (e.g., `reactiveValues(A = 1, Aa = 1, Ab = 1)`), but this approach entails a series of issues, notably when trying to remove some of its elements (see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2439)). Therefore, I'd like to know if there's a workaround in this case.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button_Aa", "Update Aa"),
  actionButton("button_Ab", "Update Ab"),
  p('A'),
  verbatimTextOutput("text_A"),
  p('Aa'),
  verbatimTextOutput("text_Aa"),
  p('Ab'),
  verbatimTextOutput("text_Ab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(A = list(a = 1, b = 1))
  
  observeEvent(input$button_Aa, {
    rv$A$a <- rv$A$a + 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button_Ab, {
    rv$A$b <- rv$A$b + 1
  })
  
  output$text_A <- renderPrint({
    rv$A
    rnorm(1)
  })
  
  output$text_Aa <- renderPrint({
    rv$A$a
    rnorm(1)
  })
  
  output$text_Ab <- renderPrint({
    rv$A$b
    rnorm(1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `bindEvent`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button_Aa", "Update Aa"),
  actionButton("button_Ab", "Update Ab"),
  p('A'),
  verbatimTextOutput("text_A"),
  p('Aa'),
  verbatimTextOutput("text_Aa"),
  p('Ab'),
  verbatimTextOutput("text_Ab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(A = list(a = 1, b = 1))
  
  observeEvent(input$button_Aa, {
    rv$A$a <- rv$A$a + 1
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button_Ab, {
    rv$A$b <- rv$A$b + 1
  })
  
  output$text_A <- renderPrint({
    rv$A
  })
  
  output$text_Aa <- renderPrint({
    rv$A$a
  }) |> bindEvent(input$button_Aa, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  output$text_Ab <- renderPrint({
    rv$A$b
  }) |> bindEvent(input$button_Ab, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `output` variable assignments inside the `observeEvent` calls, and then use `isolate`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button_Aa", "Update Aa"),
  actionButton("button_Ab", "Update Ab"),
  p('A'),
  verbatimTextOutput("text_A"),
  p('Aa'),
  verbatimTextOutput("text_Aa"),
  p('Ab'),
  verbatimTextOutput("text_Ab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(A = list(a = 1, b = 1))
  
  observeEvent(input$button_Aa, {
    rv$A$a <- rv$A$a + 1
    output$text_Aa <- renderPrint({
      isolate(rv$A$a)
      rnorm(1)
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button_Ab, {
    rv$A$b <- rv$A$b + 1
    output$text_Ab <- renderPrint({
      isolate(rv$A$b)
      rnorm(1)
    })
  })
  
  output$text_A <- renderPrint({
    rv$A
    rnorm(1)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```